# jQuery .animate() not executing

Tags: jquery

I am using .animate to try and create a tile based game. I am mixing jQuery with another ajax script to try and make this work. I keep clicking an arrow to move but get no result. Maybe someone else would understand why?

Buttons:

```
$data .= "<center><table><tr><td></td><td><button onclick=\"transition(\'up\')\">&uarr;</button></td> <td></td></tr><tr><td><button onclick=\"transition(\'left\')\">&larr;</button></td> <td></td> <td><button onclick=\"transition(\'right\')\">&rarr;</button></td></tr><tr><td></td> <td><button  onclick=\"transition(\'down\')\">&darr;</button></td> <td></td></tr></table></center>";
```

Map:

```
$data .= "<div style=\'width:480px;height:480px;background-color:#000000;background-image:url(".$map['background'].");padding:".$map['locationpadding'].";\' id=\'locationMap\'>";


$data .= "<div id=\'specialLocations\'></div>";


$data .= "<div style=\'position:absolute;left:".$charrel[0]."px;bottom:".$charrel[1]."px;width:32px;height:32px;background-image:url(".$char['charimage'].");\' id=\'charLocation\'></div>";


$data .= "</div>";
```

Finally, getting the animation. I have made sure the if statements are all working. So everything is working fine up to this point.

```
if($_POST['direction'] == "up"){

        print("$('#charLocation').animate({'bottom': '+=50px'}, 'slow');");

    }elseif($_POST['direction'] == "left"){

        print("$('#charLocation').animate({'left': '-=50px'}, 'slow');");

    }elseif($_POST['direction'] == "right"){

    print("$('#charLocation').animate({'left': '+=50px'}, 'slow');");

    }elseif($_POST['direction'] == "down"){

    print("$('#charLocation').animate({'bottom': '-=50px'}, 'slow');");

    }else{
        die('alert("Invalid movement.");');
    }
```

And the reasoning for printing the jQuery/JavaScript code through PHP is that everything is loaded via Ajax code so I am never printing.

Sorry for any confusion ahead of time and thanks for looking over this for me.

Comment: Insufficient data. There could be many reasons, such as function name conflict with your "another ajax script" or maybe missing `<script>` tags around your jQuery code (as you don't seem to print them). Care to put the code online and link to it?

Comment: You have a lots of problem and most importantly the approach is wrong and probably no one is able to make it fixed. I think you should read more about `php` and `javascript`.

Comment: And it couldn't hurt to read up on javascript based game design. There are tons of resources out there if you just google search "javascript game development" or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your approach to making a game with these languages. If you want to move a character in a web based tile game you should control all game logic in the front end client side - in javascript in this case - and only use ajax to push critical game info to the server. Like, if you move a chess piece for example, you only post the new piece coordinates when the animation completes, not calling ajax and executing whatever comes back from the server.

I don't think an example can be provided in this case since it is an issue with the foundation of your approach.

I could answer specific questions if you have them. To answer your current question - printing a line of javascript as an ajax request won't automatically execute the response as javascript, nor should it. Don't try to get it to work this way. Instead restructure your approach to not require this kind of behavior to operate.

Comment: Would this have anything to do with it?

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js. Origin http://thefallenimmortals.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: If the jquery library isn't loading then there is definitely a problem. But it is still not the reason why this approach won't work.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest jquery and hosting it on your server?